# Azure Function App suddenly stopped working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have an Azure Function App that generates random names. Suddenly, it stopped working - the response is 403. I made no changes to code nor settings.

When I go to Azure Portal, I see that the app is disabled (although individual functions are enabled).

[image]

When I try things like 'Diagnose and solve problems' or even 'get support', I get the following error:

[image]

The other things on my subscription are running fine and there's plenty of credit remaining...

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Do you set any firewall settings on the storage of the function app?

Comment: The content of the function app is stored on the storage. So did you set any firewall settings?

Comment: Or something errors when create, have a look of this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43203

Comment: Nope, it worked and then suddenly stopped, I did nothing, I promise;)

Comment: Are you using "consumption billing" or App Service Plan? If "App Service Plan" and if it's free or shared, it has limits that disable the function.

The **Free Tier** is limited to 60 CPU minutes per day
The **Shared Tier** is limited to 240 CPU minutes per day

Comment: @Ricardo - I thought about that, but I was under an impression that functions have first million of execution/month for free? Also, I get a similar error page when trying to view the app service plan from within the function - so cannot even check or scale up.

Comment: In that case it's not related to the limits of service plan. Checks the audits logs of your resource group to see what may happen. maybe someone other than you delete or disable the resource

Comment: were you able to resolve this?